# C program with fully justification of text from file

Tags: c, string, file

Here is my problem statement:

[image]

I have a small question related to a portion of code which I can't find a proper solution to. Again I'm not necessarily asking for a full solution I just hit a deadend. I need to read from a file lines (Don't know their lengths) find the maximum length of a line and add spaces between words on each line, evenly, so that they are fully justified (all lines have the same size as the max one).

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f;
    char *word;
    int j, i, m, n, c, k, z;
    char aux[255] = "", aux1[255];
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    char file[100][100];
    char s[100];
    f = fopen("user_input.txt", "r");
    m = 0;

    while (fgets(file[i], sizeof(file[i]), f)) {
        if (m < strlen(file[i]) - 1)
            m = strlen(file[i]) - 1;
        i++;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        n = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < strlen(file[j]); k++)
            if (file[j][k] == ' ')
                n++;

        c = (m - strlen(file[j])) / n;

        for (z = 0; z < c; z++)
            aux[z] = ' ';

        for (k = 0; k < strlen(file[j]); k++)
            if (file[j][k] == ' ') {
                strcpy(aux1, file[j] + k + 1);
                strcat(file[j], aux);
                strcat(file[j], aux1);
            }

        printf("%s", file[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the exact problem? Which line, function, etc? 2) This code is very poorly formatted.

Comment: It looks like you are attacking the basics of how to read lines, get lengths, find spaces, and insert spaces, which is good. But there's no sign of a strategy -- you need to break the problem down into manageable steps. Read the file, break it into lines, deal with one line at a time, determine how many spaces to add, determine where to add them, actually add them in, and finally produce your output. It will help if you use variable names / function names / comments that make it clear what each part of the code is doing.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I'll attach a pic with the actual program

Comment: you should add #include <string.h> this is need for the strlen. Make sure the file exist in the place.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I added it,it only aligns the first line so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is broken for multiple reasons:

- you forgot to include `<string.h>`
- you have hard coded limits to the maximum line length and the number of lines, both causing a penalty of 0.5p
- you do not test for `fopen()` success, causing undefined behavior upon failure to open the file.
- you do not test array boundaries when reading lines, causing undefined behavior if the file has more than 100 lines or 99 byte fragments thereof.
- your computation of `c = (m - strlen(file[j])) / n;` is rounded down. You will not insert enough spaces for full text justification in many cases.
- `aux` is not properly null terminated, it will keep growing up to the largest number of spaces to insert for any given line.
- the insertion operation will corrupt the line and ultimately leave just the last word with some spaces inserted before.
- the code was badly formated and since you do not use `{}` for non trivial statement, it is difficult to read and easy to break.

Here is a modified version that does not have such limitations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *filename = "user_input.txt";
    FILE *f;
    char *line;
    int c, i, len, maxlen, skip, nw, spaces, ns;

    /* open the file */
    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    /* first pass: determine the maximum line length */
    for (maxlen = len = 0;;) {
        c = getc(f);
        if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) {
            if (maxlen < len)
                maxlen = len;
            len = 0;
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        } else {
            len++;
        }
    }

    /* allocate the line buffer: maxlen characters plus newline plus '\0' */
    if ((line = malloc(maxlen + 2)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d bytes\n", maxlen + 2);
        fclose(f);
        return 1;
    }

    /* second pass: read one line at a time */
    rewind(f);
    while (fgets(line, maxlen + 2, f)) {
        len = strlen(line);
        if (len > 0 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            /* strip the newline if any */
            line[--len] = '\0';
        }
        /* skip and output initial spaces */
        for (skip = 0; line[skip] == ' '; skip++) {
            putchar(line[skip]);
        }
        /* count the words */
        for (nw = 0, i = skip; i < len; i++) {
            if (line[i] == ' ')
                nw++;
        }
        /* output the text, expanding spaces */
        spaces = maxlen - len;
        for (i = skip; i < len; i++) {
            if (line[i] == ' ') {
                ns = spaces / nw;
                printf("%*s", ns, "");
                spaces -= ns;
                nw--;
            }
            putchar(line[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your analysis looks sound, but do you really think it appropriate to provide the OP a complete solution to an exam problem?  This could expose him to a charge of cheating even if a complete solution is not something he wanted in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, I now understand better how this problem should've been implemented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I guess you are right, I did not see the heading *Computer programming exam, Part II*, but I think the OP is more likely training on past exam questions rather than taking this exam right now. Giving exams to students with full Internet access would be calling for trouble anyway. I provided a complete solution with didactic comments for teaching purposes. I was easier than I initially thought.  The problem statement should be made more precise regarding lines with initial or trailing spaces or multiple adjacent spaces. A more precise definition of *evenly* would be welcome too.